How to create ios shortcut that opens deeplink to Health data
A friend monitoring a health condition wants to regularly check the Heart rate minute by minute data on Apple Health on their iPhone but this requires multiple clicks and scrolls until “show all data” in the HR section is finally revealed.
How can I create a shortcut that will take them directly to the screen that shows the list of daily data with one touch ?

You can use the Open URL action with the URL x-apple-health://SampleType/HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate to get to the Heart Rate page. You do still need to tap "Show All Data," but that will get you a lot closer.
